# Warnings in Flex Builder

Tags: flex4, warnings, swc

in my current project i use three swc-Files (mate.swc, SQLExtensions and Thunderbolt).
Unfortunately, in the problems view, i receive for each file the following warning: Design mode could not load Mate_08_9.swc. It may be incompatible with this SDK, or invalid.

I don't want supress all warnings in general. But it will very helpful to supress these warnings, specialy i receive it for all files in my project three times.

Do you have a idea, if its possible?

Thank you
Frank

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing this somewhere, it's either a Flash Builder or a SDK issue. I think you need to update to the 4.1 version of both products

Comment: adobe says: there is no issue in design. Their says, the swc is incompatible. I'm currently using the FB burrito and flex hero. Both are the prev Version of nexct generation. But i have the warnings also on FB4.1 with actual sdk.